# How to ask for phone calling request on Android

Tags: android

I have a button that will make a phone call with the user number. But whenever i pressed call without allow the permission it crash the app. Does anyone know how can i implement the phone call request? I searched on the internet about the related topic but still couldn't understand clearly how to do it.

My code

```
        //call phone button click event
        holder.buttonCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+model.getPhoneNumber()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }

        });
```

Comment: if it's crashing  because it needs a permission, then you should handle the request for the permission. there are loads and loads of resources available for doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in AndroidManifest.xml add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>`

before start intent get from user permission if not granted yet.

```
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission in your menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```